A complicated numerical integration
I'm performing a numerical integration
$$
\begin{align}
    I(x)&=\int\mathcal{Q}(q_1,q_2,q_3)(1+q_1^x-q_2^x-q_3^x)(q_1q_2q_3)^{-x}\delta(1+q_1-q_2-q_3)dq_1dq_2dq_3,\quad q_i>0\nonumber\\
    &=\int_0^{\infty}dq_1\int_0^{1+q_1}\mathcal{Q}(q_1,q_2,1+q_1-q_2)[1+q_1^x-q_2^x-(1+q_1-q_2)^x][q_1q_2(1+q_1-q_2)]^{-x}dq_2,\\
\end{align}
$$
where $\delta(1+q_1-q_2-q_3)$ is a Dirac delta function, and
$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal Q(q_1,q_2,q_3)&=\int_0^{\infty} J_0(a)J_0(a\sqrt{q_1})J_0(a\sqrt{q_2})J_0(a\sqrt{q_3})ada
\end{align}
$$
where $J_0()$ is the Bessel functions. To handle the upper limit of infinity, I substitute $a=\tanh^{-1}(b), da=(1-b^2)^{-1}db$, such that
$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal Q(q_1,q_2,q_3)&=\int_0^{1} J_0[\tanh^{-1}(b)]J_0[\tanh^{-1}(b)\sqrt{q_1}]
 J_0[\tanh^{-1}(b)\sqrt{q_2}]J_0[\tanh^{-1}(b)\sqrt{q_3}]\frac{\tanh^{-1}(b)}{1-b^2}db
\end{align}
$$
The code I tried is
x = 1.5;
q3 = 1 + q1 - q2;
part1 = BesselJ[0, ArcTanh[b]] BesselJ[0, 
    ArcTanh[b] Sqrt[q1]] BesselJ[0, ArcTanh[b] Sqrt[q2]] BesselJ[0, 
    ArcTanh[b] Sqrt[q3]] ArcTanh[b]/(1 - b^2);
part2 = (1 + q1^x - q2^x - q3^x)  (q1  q2  q3)^(-x);
eps = 10^-8;
NIntegrate[
 part1  part2 , {q1, eps, 1, Infinity}, {q2, eps, 1, 
  1 + q1 - eps}, {b, 0, 1 - eps}, PrecisionGoal -> 10, 
 AccuracyGoal -> 10]

However, it does not seem to work as expected.
I appreciate any help you can provide, and thank you in advance!

Why are you specifying the integration ranges with three values? I ran your code, using Mathematica 11.2.0 for Windows, after changing your ranges to e. g. {q1, eps, Infinity}, and got 20274.2 as the result.

I tried to edit my comment but timed out. I ran the code with eps = 10^-3, and get 37.309. Clearly the answer is sensitive to the regularization used.

Thanks @TomDickens. The intermediate values in the integration ranges help Mathematica detect singularities or other important points within the integration limits. However, even after removing the intermediate values, it still does not work in my computer. I'm using Mathematica 14.0 for Windows. Ideally, eps should be set very close to 0.

The integral with $\delta(1+q_1-q_2-q_3)$ makes no sense in traditional math. That was noticed at this forum a lot of times.

What are the integration limits q3 in your first integral?

@user64494 You claim again and again "integral with dirac makes no sense" but your statement is still not correct!

@UlrichNeumann Each $q_i$ has integration limits from  $0$ to $\infty$.

@so_sure You need two integration ranges in your NIntegrate- command:  {q1, eps, Infinity}, {q2, eps, 1 + q1 - eps} and {q1, eps, Infinity}, {q2,  1 + q1 + eps,Infinity} ! Unfortunately Mathematica v12.2 can't solve it

@UlrichNeumann Nevertheless, $q_2$ should be less than $1+q_1$. Because $\delta(1+q_1-q_2-q_3)$ requires $q_3=1+q_1-q_2$, and the constraint $q_3>0$ implies that $q_2<1+q_1$.

@so_sure Correct, thanks for your explanation!

@so_sure Sorry, I had forgotten about the capability to specify singular points! It hit me during the night... Could you let us know what problem gives rise to this integral?

@TomDickens Yes, it's a long story.... We're working on a problem closely similar to the one in this paper with a similar derivation process leading up to this integral. However, performing this integration is essential (see also Fig. 1 in the Supplemental Material of the related paper).

Here a workaround, which uses transformed integral and Gaussian quadrature in a fixed mesh
It is obvious that the same transformation b=Tanh[a] should be used to get a finite interation range for q1,q2,q3
With w1=Tanh[q1],w2=Tanh[q2],w3=Tanh[q3] integrand transforms  to
\[Sigma] = 10^-3; (* definition dirac*)
dirac = Function[{z, \[Sigma]\[Sigma] }, Evaluate[Exp[-(z^2/(2 \[Sigma]\[Sigma] ))]/Sqrt[2 Pi \[Sigma]\[Sigma] ] ]] (*  \[Sigma] small *)

fun = Function[{w1, w2, w3, b}, 
dirac[1 + ArcTanh[w1] - ArcTanh[w2] -ArcTanh[w3], \[Sigma]]
ArcTanh[b]/(1 - b^2)
BesselJ[0, ArcTanh[b]] 
BesselJ[0,ArcTanh[b] Sqrt[ArcTanh[w1]]] 
BesselJ[0,ArcTanh[b] Sqrt[ArcTanh[w2]]] 
BesselJ[0,ArcTanh[b] Sqrt[ArcTanh[w3]]] 
(1 + ArcTanh[w1]^x - ArcTanh[w2]^x -ArcTanh[w3]^
      x) (ArcTanh[w1] ArcTanh[w2] ArcTanh[w3])^(-x) 
1/((1 - w1^2) (1 -w2^2) (1 - w3^2))]

Integration range 0<w1<1,0<w2<1,0<w3<1,0<b<1
Unfortunately Mathematica v12.2 isn't able to solve the integral I[x]=NIntegrate[fun[w1,w2,w3,b], ...].
That's why I try a solution using Gaussian quadrature in a fixed grid (x variabel)
Get["NumericalDifferentialEquationAnalysis`"];

x=. (* variable x *)
xi = Subdivide[0, 1, 10];  (* Diskretisierung *)
xwGauss = 
 (* in jeder Teildiskretisierung wird 3-Punkt Gauss verwendet *)
  Flatten[
  Map[GaussianQuadratureWeights[3(*5*), #[[1]], #[[2]]] & , 
   Partition[xi, 2, 1]], 1] ;
grid = xwGauss[[All, 1]]; (* 1D gauss points*)
gew = xwGauss[[All, 2]];  (* 1D gauss weights*)
list = grid;
pts4D = Outer[List, list, list, list, list]  // Flatten[#, 1] & // 
    Flatten[#, 1] & // Flatten[#, 1] &; (* 4D gauss points*)
list = gew;
gew4D = Outer[Times, list, list, list, list]  // Flatten[#, 1] & // 
    Flatten[#, 1] & // Flatten[#, 1] &; (* 4D gauss weights*)
xwGauss4D = MapThread[{#1, #2} &, {pts4D, gew4D}];

integration
int = Total@Map [#[[2]] Apply[fun, #[[1]]] &, xwGauss4D]; (* takes some time *)

check solution
Plot[int, {x, 1/2, 3/2} , AxesLabel -> {"x", "I[x]"},PlotRange->All]



Excellent answer!

@so_sure Thanks, hope it helps. Perhaps you might improve the result using ,eps=10^-3,xi = Subdivide[eps, 1 - eps, 10] ;  to approximate  "Cauchy Principal Value"  . Playing around with eps hopefully gives a converging result

No idea why Mathematica doesn't evaluate your code.
Here my approach, which uses a numerical approximation of DiracDelta as a limit Limit[dirac[u,\[Sigma]],\[Sigma]->0]=DiracDelta[u]
dirac = Function[{z, \[Sigma] }, Evaluate[Exp[-(z^2/(2 \[Sigma] ))]/Sqrt[2 Pi \[Sigma] ] ]] (*  \[Sigma] small *)

integral I[x]~int[x,\[Sigma],eps]
 int[x_?NumericQ, \[Sigma]_?NumericQ, eps_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[
  dirac[1 + q1 - q2 - q3, \[Sigma]] BesselJ[0, ArcTanh[b]] BesselJ[0, 
    ArcTanh[b] Sqrt[q1]] BesselJ[0, ArcTanh[b] Sqrt[q2]] BesselJ[0, 
    ArcTanh[b] Sqrt[q3]] ArcTanh[b]/(1 - b^2) (1 + q1^x - q2^x - 
     q3^x) (q1 q2 q3)^(-x), {q1, 0, Infinity}, {q2, 0, Infinity}, {q3,
    0, Infinity}, {b, 0, 1 - eps}, AccuracyGoal -> 10  ]

For  different  \[Sigma],eps Mathematica v12.2 evaluates  nearly zero for the integral I[3/2]
Table[{int[3/2, \[Sigma], eps], \[Sigma], eps}, {\[Sigma], 10^- Range[2, 5]}, {eps, 10^- Range[2, 5]}]

   (* {{{-6.21694*10^-16, 0.01, 0.01}, {2.26795*10^-17, 0.01, 
   0.001}, {-6.67927*10^-19, 0.01, 0.0001}, {-2.15971*10^-18, 0.01, 
   0.00001}}, {{9.29367*10^-216, 0.001, 0.01}, {2.32465*10^-216, 
   0.001, 0.001}, {-6.62587*10^-216, 0.001, 
   0.0001}, {-7.81607*10^-216, 0.001, 0.00001}}, {{0., 0.0001, 
   0.01}, {0., 0.0001, 0.001}, {0., 0.0001, 0.0001}, {0., 0.0001, 
   0.00001}}, {{0., 0.00001, 0.01}, {0., 0.00001, 0.001}, {0., 
   0.00001, 0.0001}, {0., 0.00001, 0.00001}}}*)

Hope it helps!
addendum
Also the original definition of Q works. In this case no parameter eps is needed!
 inta[x_?NumericQ, \[Sigma]_?NumericQ ] := 
 NIntegrate[
  dirac[1 + q1 - q2 - q3, \[Sigma]] a BesselJ[0, a] BesselJ[0, 
    a Sqrt[q1]] BesselJ[0, a Sqrt[q2]] BesselJ[0, 
    a Sqrt[q3]] (1 + q1^x - q2^x - q3^x) (q1 q2 q3)^(-x), {q1, 0, 
   Infinity}, {q2, 0, Infinity}, {q3, 0, Infinity}, {a, 0, Infinity} ,
   AccuracyGoal -> 10   , PrecisionGoal -> 5]

inta[3/2, 10^-3 ] (*5.88194*10^-216*)  


Thank you Neumann.  Unfortunately,  the numerical approximation of DiracDelta does not seem accurate in this context. I tested several different values of $x$, all returned $0$. Your another answer provides a similar approach that can confirm this discrepancy.

@so_sure I think it's a numerical problem, not an approximation problem of DiracDelta.
